# JavaScript equivalent of "nansum" from MATLAB?

Tags: javascript

I’m trying to compute the sum of an array with more than 10 000 values in it that contains some `NaN`. I’ve done a fair bit of research on this and didn’t find an adequate answer.

Using the `reduce` function works fine if my array doesn’t contain any `NaN`.

```
.reduce((pv, cv) => pv+cv, 0)
```

But is there a quick way to achieve that, like `nansum` in MATLAB, without looping the entire array, removing the `NaN` and then computing the sum?

Comment: you can just add an `if` condition inside to check if it's a number

Comment: `.reduce((pv, cv) => pv+(isNaN(cv) ? 0 : cv), 0)`

Comment: NaN is a number in js

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In Javascript, how to avoid NaN when adding arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1885079/in-javascript-how-to-avoid-nan-when-adding-arrays)

Comment: @Oleksii thats crazy to think about, especially when you consider `NaN` = NOT a number

Comment: @Derek try typeof Nan in a console

Comment: @Oleksii I know it is a number type, the actual LETTERS NaN stand for Not a Number

Answer (score 2):

You can check in the reduce function if `cv` [`isNaN`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN) and substitute `0` if it is:

```
.reduce((pv, cv) => pv + (isNaN(cv) ? 0 : cv), 0)
```

Comment: This won't work if the first element is a `NaN` as pv will be NaN.
I suggest : 
.reduce((pv, cv) => (isNaN(pv) ? 0 : pv) + (isNaN(cv) ? 0 : cv), 0)

Comment: Dude, `[NaN,NaN,1,2].reduce((pv, cv) => pv + (isNaN(cv) ? 0 : cv), 0)` clearly returns 3. Don't say something doesn't work without checking, especially on code that easy to check!

Comment: Thank you for your kindness and comprehension nowhere man but I did test it, I only made a mistake by removing the `,0)` at the end of the line. In this case, having the first element as NaN won't work.

Answer (score 1):

You can just remove the `NaN`s before reducing:

```
.filter( (n) => !isNaN(n) )
.reduce( (pv, cv) => pv + cv )
```

I'm not sure if there's a significant difference between this and bhmaker's answer, except that an optimizing compiler might be able to optimize this better.